# Install rEFInd on Ubuntu (dual-boot mac)

Tags: dual-boot, macosx, refind

I have problems with installing rEFInd on mac, because I can't disable SIP via crutil. While restart it will be enabled every time. (Already tried 20 times)

So it is possible to install rEFInd on dual boot Ubuntu?

Comment: The command is `csrutil`, not `crutil`. If you've been typing the latter, then that's the problem. I recommend you read the [rEFInd documentation on SIP](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/sip.html), which describes several ways to get it to work.